# the function doesnt execute when i send it to it parent extracted widget

Tags: function, flutter, flutter-widget

so this function

```
Buttons(
         '1',
          () {
             setState(() {
               visibleText = '1';
                 });
                },
               ),
```

doesnt work when i press the button but if i do this like this it works:

```
Expanded(
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
               visibleText = '1';
                 });
            },
            child: Card(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 65),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

is there some thing i am not understanding. sorry if the indentations are wrong.

the const.dart file just has one variable for fontSize so i didnt bother to attach it.

i also put a print statement in the Buttons '1' and it didnt print so it seems like the function isnt being executed on the press

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:calculator/const.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
String visibleText = '0';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int computationalCount;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('Calculator'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                child: Text(
                  visibleText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Buttons(
                  'C',
                  () {
                    visibleText = '';
                    computationalCount = 0;
                  },
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '( )',
                  () {
                    int num = 0;
                    if (num / 2 == 0) {
                      visibleText += '(';
                    } else {
                      visibleText += ')';
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '^',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '<=',
                  () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Buttons(
                  '1',
                  () {
                    setState(() {
                      visibleText = '1';
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '2',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '3',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '+',
                  () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Buttons(
                  '4',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '5',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '6',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '-',
                  () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Buttons(
                  '7',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '8',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '9',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '×',
                  () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Buttons(
                  '.',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '0',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '÷',
                  () {},
                ),
                Buttons(
                  '=',
                  () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final onPress;
  const Buttons(this.text, this.onPress);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // ignore: unnecessary_statements
          onPress;
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 65),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pleasae be more clean in your question, you are calling a Widget like button and I can't see what's the question, try to see the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for best practice define the type of attribut,     final Function onPress;

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Buttons widget for it to receive a GestureCallback, like this:

```dart
class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed; // add the type here
  const Buttons(this.text, this.onPress);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: onPressed, //onPressed should now be like this
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 65),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```